# Where can OSGI be applied?

Tags: java, architecture, osgi

In the [OSGI Alliance](http://www.osgi.org/About/WhyOSGi) site says "... integrates multiple devices in a networked environment..." "... The OSGi component system is actually used to build highly complex applications like IDEs (Eclipse), application servers..." "... industrial automation, residential gateways, phones, and so much more. "

Industrial automation? sounds interesting. I could think of a Monitoring System and I found some google results related to embbeded systems for cars

Anyone know more places where osgi can be applied?

Comment: I'd say this is off-topic for SO. Nevertheless, IMHO this is one of the more interesting ones: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipsert/case_studies/siemens.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OSGi is specifically a generic module system. It tries not to be biased towards a certain field. Although it originated from the embedded field, I think a very small percentage of the developers who use OSGi now are in that field.

I think any code with a reasonable complexity will benefit from some kind of modularisation framework, and OSGi is a very good choice, although there are some obstacles:

- OSGi is java based, so non java projects are out. (Unless you are feeling adventurous and want to try something like [Apache Celix](http://incubator.apache.org/celix/))
- Some libraries that do certain classloading tricks might not play nice with OSGi (for example Hibernate)
- OSGi has a bit of a learning curve, so be prepared to invest some time and effort.

Answer (score 5):

OSGi is a way to apply modularity to a code base, pretty much regardless of the target application, though modularity kicks more ass the bigger the code base. Very tight real time programs probably not, but if you're ok with Java and running on a JVM, then OSGi should be viable. It's more about how you build your code than what it's for. I recommend [Java Application Architecture: Modularity Patterns with Examples Using OSGi (Agile Software Development Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321247132) to understand the motivation for OSGi.

Answer (score 1):

- Smart Homes - for device control, control of energy consumption, remote support, remote software provisioning, home automation - for examples of implemented projects see  [the OSGi page for Smart Home use cases](http://www.osgi.org/Markets/SmartHome)
- Mobile - smart phones - examples - see the above link again
- Vehicle - remote control, support, reading of sensors, providing navi and other services
- assisted living - many projects, since there remote management is very important
- any big software application - for adding modularity and management of plugins. Example - Eclipse ;)
  ...

Answer (score -2):

No, embedded vehicle systems in fact the only viable OSGi application;-)